# How long does it take for a CRM instance to restore?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

1.It has been 4+ hours that my instance is getting restored. Is it normal?

2.As per the documentation provided by MS, it says, instance remains unavailable while restoring. Yet, I am able to access to the instance and so, is my application able to connect.
Is there a way to know if the restoration has failed or it is stuck somewhere?

Comment: If something is going wrong with a restore you can open a Microsoft support ticket via the Office 365 Admin portal.

Comment: Result: it took 4+ hours just to prepare the instance. And then 36 minutes to restore the instance. At that time the instance was unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are doing full-copy (schema+data), then your Org DB size decides the time based on stored data. Schema-only copy will be quicker than the full-copy.